# How to call fetched method in ClientSide to receive an array from ServerSide?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

**ServerSide (app.js):**

I get some data from DB and put it in an array

```
app.post('/sendform', (req,res) =>{
        var array = [{"h":"1"},{"e","2"}];
        res.send(array);
)}
```

**ClientSide (client.js):**

I want to get that array and add it to my index.html

```
function tableContent(){
     fetch('/')
        .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        if(res.ok) return res.json();


 });
     .then(data => {

         //do something with html file
     });

}
```

Comment: BTW my post method invokes by a form in my html.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. You have an express POST route on the url, `sendForm`, but you have the client making a GET request to `/`. You need a route to handle the `/` request if you want the client to get anything from it.

Comment: you can't get that same array. You'll have to write an other endpoint `/` to get the data that you want

Answer (score 0):

```
    var URL = “127.0.0.1:3000/sendform”;

    var req = new Request(URL, {method: 'POST', cache: 'reload'});

    fetch(req).then(function(response) {
        var reader = response.body.getReader();
        return reader.read();
    }).then(function(result, done) {
        if (!done) {
        // do something with each chunk
        }
    });
```

The POST method requests your address